# How to get/set heading in collapsibleset jQm

Tags: jquery, mobile

I started some small web app by using jQuery. Some part of script consist of accordions where I was able to get and set heading (title) of active panel, write inside expanded panel... and I wished to make version for mobile device based on my jQuery experience but as I was able to get what is ID of active panel (collapsible) in collapsible-set now I can't figure out how to get header or title between

#### Title of panel 1

tags of expanded collapsible.
Is there someone who could direct me to some reference (on web/book) where is possible to see and learn all these misty words of options jQuery mobile UI controls?
I saw some iu-collapsible-heading etc. options but simply I don't understand how to plug it into my code; by using jQuery it was easy in comparison with mobile version. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made solution for your problem, not elegant but it's working. Trick is at first to find out ID of expanded collapsible-set panel and then read Title between "h3" tags of known ID. Small trouble made option *expandedCueText* with default contents " click to expand contents", because it appears as part of title expanded collapsible but I removed it programmatically. Maybe there is better solution, with less code, but I didn't see it.
Here is

```
[copy link text](https://jsfiddle.net/Ludus/s3o78owh/9/)
```

In meantime I made some improvement to this script, so I think it would satisfy your needs until you wait for better solution.

Comment: You didn't mention what jQmobile version, this is made for 1.4.2